# Logando em um site usando WebRequest

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

Preciso logar em um site usando o asp.net web forms. Estou fazendo desta forma. Como eu poderia redirecionar para a página após logado?

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var loginAddress = "http://sportone.sisguardiao.com.br/";
            var loginData = new NameValueCollection
                    {
                      { "LOGIN", "abfg" },
                      { "SENHA", "123" }
                    };
            Login(loginAddress, loginData);

        }

        public void Login(string loginPageAddress, NameValueCollection loginData)
        {
            CookieContainer container;

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginPageAddress);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginData.ToString());
            request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            container = request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            var response = request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Amigo, poderia dar uma ajuda com o seu grande conhecimento? agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Faça `Login` devolver `bool`:

```
    public bool Login(string loginPageAddress, NameValueCollection loginData)
    {
        try 
        {
            CookieContainer container;

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginPageAddress);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginData.ToString());
            request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            container = request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            var response = request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

No evento do botão:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var loginAddress = "http://sportone.sisguardiao.com.br/";
        var loginData = new NameValueCollection
                {
                  { "LOGIN", "abfg" },
                  { "SENHA", "123" }
                };

        if (Login(loginAddress, loginData))
            Server.Transfer("Pagina.aspx", true);
    }
```

Ou, ainda, se vocÊ quer redirecionar para um endereço fixo, use, ao invés de `Server.Transfer`:

```
Response.Redirect("http://sportone.sisguardiao.com.br");
```

Comment: este   Server.Transfer("Pagina.aspx", true); seria para a página "http://sportone.sisguardiao.com.br/" desta forma ela estaria logada?

Comment: A página é sua?

Comment: Sim, quero redirecionar para "http://sportone.sisguardiao.com.br/"; apos fazer o login na página

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja se te atende.

Comment: Redirecionou mais não estava logado, deveria esta logado

Comment: Aí você precisa conferir `response`. É neste objeto que está definido se o login deu certo ou não.

Comment: Ele retornou como true

Comment: aqui seria o ID do campo e senha { "LOGIN", "abfg" }, { "SENHA", "123" }